# Does $f'(x)=0$ implies Max/min or point of inflection

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, derivatives, maxima-minima

Let $f$ be a differentiable function on $(a,b)$ such that $f'(c)=0$ for some $c\in (a,b)$. Also there is no maximum or minimum at $c$ .Does this means $c$ is point of inflection?

Consider $f(x)=x^3$ , this is true. But I want to know if it is true in general. I try to find counter example but can't get any. I hope this is true. If it is please give a hint to begin a proof

Edit : hint this question by maxima / minima, I mean strict maxima or minima

Comment: *If* it's differential (big if) then $f'(c) =0$ means is an extreme point.  Geometrically this means the slope is zero.  This is either a local min or max or inflection point.  As you know it's neither of two of the options, it must be the third option.

Comment: @fleablood: I don't believe you're correct. A (local) extreme point is by definition a (local) maximum or minimum. So $f'(c)=0$ does NOT imply that $c$ is a local extreme point.

Comment: @fleablood could you elaborate your comment as answer please...I didn't get what you mean by if it's differential

Comment: One can define a minimum/maximum as a point $c$ around which there is an interval, perhaps very small $(a,b); a < c< b$ where for all $a< x < b;x\ne c$ then $f(x) > f(c)$ (0r $f(x) < f(c)$) and we can prove at max/min $f'(c)=0$ with intermediate value theorem.... But what is the definition of an "inflection point"? I can only think of it as a point where the rate of change flattens. i.e. f$f'(c)=0$ but not max or min.  If so, nothing to prove.  It's a definition.

Comment: @TedShifrin Depends on your definitions.  I was always taught that an inflection point was an extrema.

Comment: I think you need to check your definitions carefully, @fleablood.

Comment: Actually you're right.  I was thinking of the term "critical points".

Comment: @fleablood doesn't your answer contradict N.S answer?      I can only think of it as a point where the rate of change flattens. i.e. $f′(c)=0$.....I think you mean $f"(c)=0$

Comment: @fleablood It is true that local extremum implies critical point, I think you confuse this with the converese which is not true. And inflection point is typically defined as a point where the concavity changes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Consider the function 
$$g(x)=x\sin(\frac{1}{x})$$
with $g(0)=0$.
This function is continuous on $\mathbb R$.

Let $F(x)$ be any antiderivative of $g(x)$. Then $F'(0)=0$.

Now, since $g(x)$ is an even function, $F$ is odd, and hence it cannot have a local max/min at $x=0$.

Moreover, $F(x)$ cannot have an inflection point at $x=0$, since this would imply that for some $(0,a)$ the function $g(x)$ would be monotonic.

**Added:** if $n\geq 2$, $f$ is $n$ times differentiable, $f^{(n)}$ is continuous at $c$ and 
$$f'(c)=...=f^{(n-1)}(c)=0 \\
f^{(n)}(c) \neq 0$$
then

- If $n$ is odd $c$ is an inflection point
- If $n$ is even and $f^{(n)}(c) >0$ then $c$ is a local min.

  - If $n$ is even and $f^{(n)}(c) <0$ then $c$ is a local max.

**Sketch Proof:** Since $f^{(n)}(c) \neq 0$ it is either positive or negative.

If $f^{(n)}(c)<0$ then replace $f$ by $-f$. Note that in the case $n$ even thiwill change local max to min.

By continuity, there exists some $a>0$ such that $f^{(n)}>0$ on $(c-a, c+a)$.

Now you do an inductive argument.  $f^{(n)}>0$ on $(c-a, c+a)$ means $f^{(n-1)}$ is strictly increasing on $(c-a, c+a)$ and thus, since $f^{(n-1)}(c)=0$ you get
$$f^{n-1}(x) <0 \forall x \in (c-a,c) \\
f^{n-1}(x) >0 \forall x \in (c,c-a) (*)\\$$

This gives that $f^{n-2}$ is decreasing on (c-a,c)$ and increasing on $(c,c+a)$. Therefore
$$f^{n-2}(x) >0 \forall x \in (c-a,c) \
f^{n-2}(x) >0 \forall x \in (c,c-a) (**)\$$

Then, same argument shows that 
$$f^{n-3}(x) <0 \forall x \in (c-a,c) \\
f^{n-3}(x) >0 \forall x \in (c,c-a) (*)\\$$

and so on, with (*) and (**)alternating. Based of $n$ being odd or even, either $f'$ or $f''$ will satisfy $(*)$ [this is why we need $n \geq 2$].

Now, if $f'$ satisfies $(*)$ then it is easy to see that $c$ is a local max.

If $f''$ satisfies $(*)$ theb it is easy to see that $c$ is an inflection point.

**QED**

**P.P.S.** The key for the proof is the existence and continuity of the first derivative which doesn't vanish at $c$. The above counterexample fails this :)

Comment: Thanks it helps a lot

Comment: @CloudJR Check my P.S. too, the claim is actually true for "nice" functions.

Comment: @CloudJR If you need the details I can sketch the idea of proof for analytic functions..."Analyticity" can actually be replaced by $f$ is $n$ times differentiable, $f^{(n)}$ is continuous and $$f'(c)=....f^{(n-1)}(c)=0 \\f^{(n)}(c) \neq 0$$

Comment: Where can I find more about this....like proof and more ..any book?

Comment: @CloudJR see the new edit.

Comment: If I remember right, let $f(x)=e^{-1/x^2}\sin{1/x}, f(0)=0$  Then $f(n)(0)=0,$ for all $n$ and $0$ is neither a local extremum nor an inflection point.

Comment: @saulspatz EXactly.That's why the condition $f^{(n)}(c)\neq 0$ is essential..  This  holds for free for non-constant analytic functions, but as that example shows it is not necessarily true for $C^\infty$ functions.

Comment: @N.S. I wasn't disputing your answer at all, just offering an extreme example.

Comment: Thanks buddy...

Answer (score 1):

The simplest counter example is the constant function 
$$
f\equiv 0
$$
on any interval $(a,b)$. Clearly $f'(c)=0$ for any $c\in(a,b)$ but it's not a point of inflection.

**Edit**: I interpreted the words max/min to mean strict minima/maxima, if the question refers to nonstrict ones then this is **not** a counter example.

Comment: But every point is a local min/max.

Comment: But every point is maximum or minimum

Comment: Yeah, I just realized that I probably misinterpreted the question. Sorry for that.